# Как отключить кнопку, пока хотя бы один из полей ввода с пустым значением?

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет.
Есть массив, который рендерит `<input>` через цикл. По-умолчанию значение `value: ''`.

Как добавить аттрибут `disabled`, при условии, что хотя бы одно поле пустое?

Спасибо.

[Песочница](https://jsfiddle.net/overus/hLgcpv7u/11/)

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inputs: [{
        value: ''
      },
      {
        value: ''
      },
      {
        value: ''
      },
    ],
    disabledButton: true,
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled() {
      return this.disabledButton;
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-for="item in inputs" type="text" />
  <button :disabled="isDisabled">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) для проверки всех `value` у `inputs` или же, можно использовать функцию [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), для того чтобы избавиться от отрицания в темплейте.

Так же, если вы хотите связать каждое `value` к своему `<input>` - необходимо использовать [v-model](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) (двухстороннее связывание).

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    inputs: [
      { value: '' },
      { value: '' },
      { value: '' },
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    isButtonEnabled() {
      return this.inputs.every(input => input.value !== '');
    },
    //  isButtonDisabled() {
    //   return this.inputs.some(input => input.value === '');
    //  },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <input v-for="(item, index) in inputs" type="text" v-model="inputs[index].value"/>
  <button :disabled="!isButtonEnabled">Button</button>
  <!-- <button :disabled="isButtonDisabled">Button</button> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.